# Python multiprocessing.dummy thread pool runs more tasks with `map` without thread initialized

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool, python-multithreading

I have the following code. I would think the initializer is run before the tasks are executed, but apparently I'm getting errors indicating some tasks are run without that thread being initialized.

```
import threading
import random
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool, Value, Queue, Manager

def init_worker():
    global thread_local
    thread_local = threading.local()
    thread_local.worker_idx = random.randint(0, 10)
    print("++++++++++++++++++++++++ worker %s" %  thread_local.worker_idx)


def run(idx):
    print(dir(thread_local))
    worker_idx = thread_local.worker_idx
    print("==================== TASK ID %s by worker %s ====================" % (idx, worker_idx))


pool = Pool(2, init_worker)
pool.map(run, range(10), chunksize=1)
```

Output:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++ worker 1
++++++++++++++++++++++++ worker 7
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'worker_idx']
==================== TASK ID 0 by worker 7 ====================
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'worker_idx']
==================== TASK ID 2 by worker 7 ====================
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'worker_idx']
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
==================== TASK ID 3 by worker 7 ====================
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'worker_idx']
==================== TASK ID 4 by worker 7 ====================
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'worker_idx']
==================== TASK ID 5 by worker 7 ====================
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'worker_idx']
==================== TASK ID 7 by worker 7 ====================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    pool.map(run, range(10), chunksize=1)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 266, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 644, in get
    raise self._value
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "test.py", line 14, in run
    worker_idx = thread_local.worker_idx
AttributeError: '_thread._local' object has no attribute 'worker_idx'
```

So looks like both threads are properly initialized, but more tasks were started without initializer being run beforehand. The output of `print(dir(thread_local))` is very inconsistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is with the initialser. Note that there are no `TASK ID ... by worker 1` print outs even though it was clear that thread one created a *global*thread local object and assigned to the `worker_idx` attribute. This is because *both* threads try to create the thread local *global* and thread 7 overwrote the thread local object that was created by thread 1 (not the `worker_idx` attr), and thus destroyed the `worker_idx` for thread 1. Instead, try creating the global in the main thread (the one that calls map). And only assign `worker_idx` in the thread initialser.